# How to access these events in content script?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, plugins, content-script

I want to implement an extension that its content script is sensitive to the events that are triggered by the below instructions and has a proper reaction against them, for example count the number of occurrence of each of these events and saving them in some varibales:

1. performance.now()
2. an assignment to an array
3. incrementing a variable (counter++ or counter=counter+1)
4. defining web worker
5. defining a SharedArrayBuffer
6. using postMessage

Which of them are possible. Do any one have a sample code for one or some of them?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has not such type events. Extension consumer should notify about these 'events' explicitly, through extension API

Comment: Would you please explain what APIs we must use in more details? thanks a lot